# Regex Expression to validate input format of Latitude and Longitude

Tags: javascript, asp.net, regex

I need to validate the just the format of the entered string for Latitude and Longitude and not if its a correct value for Latitude or Longitude.

The format Latitude 89:90:00N or 67:90:76 S and for Longitude 67:23:00E or 78:23:45W

I am using the below expression for which I am getting a false

```
 if (!Regex.IsMatch(currentValue, "^[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9][N][S]$"))

                                Errors.Text = "Invalid format of Latitude;
```

Please correct me where am I going wrong..I need to validate if its either N or S (without case sensitivity).

Comment: hm... come to think of it... was that space there on the second one a typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have made both `N` and `S` mandatory.

```
"^(?:90|[0-8][0-9]):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9][NS]$"    // latitude
"^(?:180|1[0-7][0-9]|[0-9][0-9]):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9][EW]$"  // longitude
```

should work. This will also reject invalid entries like `190:67:75E` or `99:99:99S`.

Answer (score 1):

```
/^([0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\s?[NS]|[0-9]{1,3}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\s?[EW])$/i
```

should work

Credit to Tim Pietzcker for the `^$`. I forgot to put it in mine at the first :P

Comment: OK, but now it'll fail to match longitudes over 99 degrees (they customarily go up to 180). You need two regexes, one for latitude, one for longitude.

Comment: @Tim Pietzcker  The PO didn't ask for that; only for the format: `I need to validate the just the format of the entered string for Latitude and Longitude and not if its a correct value for Latitude or Longitude`

Comment: Yes, and if the longitude entered is `104:59:59E`, it will be rejected although valid.

Comment: @Tim Pietzcker oh is that so.... didn't realize, having never actually worked with lat and lon. XD   I'll amend my answer.  Thank you very much for pointing it out.  Just looked it up... should there be provision for a `-` symbol before the number as well?

Comment: I don't think so, that's what `E` and `W` are there for. Although you could go and write `270°E` meaning `90°W`, but that would be pushing it. Well, the earth is round...

Answer (score 0):

There's an error in N/S part. As well, you can make it more readable like that:

```
if (!Regex.IsMatch(currentValue, "^\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}[SN]$"))

                            Errors.Text = "Invalid format of Latitude;
```